# Appcelerator video player shows media controls and do not play sound

Tags: ios, appcelerator

I have added Video-player in my iOS application and it shows media control even after setting `mediaControlStyle : Titanium.Media.VIDEO_CONTROL_NONE` and `showsControls : false` properties. Moreover video do not play sound on iOS devices where as it plays sound very clearly on simulator.

Setting `<property name="run-on-main-thread" type="bool">false</property>` this property to `true` hides the Media control but it causing application crash as I am calling nested functions of Web-services at the beginning of the application (immediately after splash screen). It used to work fine in previous SDK version.

Here is my code.

```
var movie = Titanium.Media.createVideoPlayer({
    url : "xyz.mp4",
    autoplay : true,
    height : Ti.UI.FILL,
    width : Ti.UI.FILL,
    mediaControlStyle : Titanium.Media.VIDEO_CONTROL_NONE,
    showsControls : false
});
```

**Appcelerator SDK:** 7.2.0.GA
**Node.js Version:** 8.9.1
**npm Version:** 5.5.1
**CLI Version:** 5.1.1

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The `showControls` part is a bug that is fixed in 7.3.0: https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/pull/9852

If you need it in 7.2.0 you can just change the file (`iphone/Classes/TiMediaVideoPlayerProxy.m`) and add the changes from the PR above. Works fine.

About the sound: make sure your device is not muted :)

Comment: No, It is not muted, It plays Youtube videos or any other video very fine with sound and I have tested it on multiple devices. I am not sure what is causing the problem for the sound. It used to play along with sound earlier.

Comment: till the release of sdk 7.3.0 is there any work around for hiding controls?

Comment: read the answer. You can just edit (check the linked PR) the file (mentioned above) yourself, save it and compile your app. Then it will work. The file is located in the SDK folder

Comment: Thanks @miga , at-least that PR solved my Media control issue . But do you have any idea why voice is not playing in the video? Do I have to make any particular changes for that? I noticed that the same video in my app playing voice in iPhone 6 Plus with iOS 11.2.1 but it is not playing voice in higher iOS version (11.3.1 and higher). And if it is iOS related issue then it should not play the sound on any other videos as well?  video format is mp4. Thanks again. :)

Answer (score 0):

On iOS 11.3 and higher Video sound is not playing on certain apps. Looks like the bug of iOS itself. This might help someone. Refer below link for more detail.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3008964

Answer (score -1):

Got around this by creating a blank.mp4 (4 seconds of white screen) and setting that to the URL of the video player at creation time.  This way the controls do not show on change.